# Why does Rust allow writing to an immutable RwLock?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rwlock

Let's say we have declared an immutable (not `let mut`) `RwLock` instance like:

```rust
let value = RwLock::new(0);
```

Because the `value` is immutable, I expected that I can not change the inner value of the `RwLock`. However when I tested, apparently this works:

```rust
{
  *value.write().unwrap() = 5;
}
```

I am wondering if I used `RwLock` in a wrong way, that this should not have happened (I am worried that the lock might not actually function as expected, if this is the case). However, I am sure there's some explanation behind this behavior since Rust is very explicit when it comes to what you can change and what not.

My guess is the `RwLock` stores its inner value on the heap so it only needs to keep track of an immutable pointer to the value. So, whenever we write to the value the `RwLock` struct itself would be kept untouched since the pointer wouldn't change.

This is just a guess, and probably a wrong one. I am more than happy if someone would like to correct me.

---

*For clarification: I know how Reader-Writer locks are supposed to work. My question is not about the synchronization mechanism, but rather why doesn't Rust treat `RwLock` values like any other value when it comes to immutability. Like is it one of the "magic" types that compiler treats differently, or there's something else I am not aware of.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are not mutating the `RwLock`, as far as the compiler is concerned.

The [`RwLock::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#method.write) takes a `&self` as the receiver and returns a `RwLockWriteGuard` for which the [`DerefMut`-impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLockWriteGuard.html#impl-DerefMut-for-RwLockWriteGuard%3C%27_%2C%20T%3E) is used to do the assignment `*value... = 5`. What happens in between those steps is up to the implementation of `RwLock`.

Since you are specifically asking not about `RwLock` per se, but the presence or non-presence of "magic": There is absolutely no magic involved here with respect to immutable (`&`) or mutable (`&mut`) references. In fact, there may be a misunderstanding:
While we call these "immutable" or "mutable" (because that's how they are used), those are better thought of as "shared" and "exclusive" references. With an exclusive reference (`&mut`), you are always free to mutate the value without causing mutation-while-aliasing; the compiler can guarantee this (special) use case.
Likewise, with shared references (`&`), you are free to alias the value as mutation is not possible. The compiler can also guarantee this (special) case.
While this covers a surprisingly large number of situations, with `RwLock` this is neither possible nor desirable. The `RwLock` uses it's internal locking mechanism (that the compiler can't know about) to determine if mutation should be allowed, and upholds the guarantee that mutation-while-aliasing does not occur. That is why `RwLock` can go from a `&self` to mutating the inner value.

The same is true for the `RefCell`-type, btw.

Comment: Deleting my half-written answer as this is clearer, but the OP might like to look at the [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) docs for this general pattern.

Comment: Nice answer, but saying that "There is absolutely no magic involved" is not entirely true - it is normally not possible to arrive from a `&` reference to an `&mut` reference to the same data. The magic that allows to do so is in `UnsafeCell` which is treated specially by the compiler, and serves as basis for not only `RwLock`, but also anything else with interior mutability, including atomics. Without that magic one would be unable to implement interior mutability, even in unsafe code.